# Authentication for Wordpress Staging Sites

Tags: wordpress

I need help with authentication for Wordpress staging sites.

Using the htaccess file is out of the question.

Is there a plugin I can use?

Or do I need to go through the proxy (using NAT and a ACL?)

Thanks :)

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to stop people from seeing the http staging site and I want to put user authentication on it. So a pop box would appear would the user needs to enter credentials to see the staging site

Answer (score 0):

I use a plugin called [Hide My Site](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-my-site/), just because it takes like 2 minutes to download and install.  Once installed just go to the settings page, check the box "Enable Password Protection", set a password and save.  It will password protect the entire site.